# Can I keep vscode Terminal connected to host machine while in Docker environment using Remote Containers extension?

Tags: vscode-remote

I have the Remote Containers extension setup so I can jump into a docker container for autocomplete etc. That's working how I want it to.

But it also sets the Terminal window to be inside that environment and I want to instead keep the Terminal window connected to my host machine. I can understand why it's useful to have Terminal from inside the container, but it's not useful for my usecase and it breaks some of my testing tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 commands in VS Code to open terminal windows when using Remote Containers extension:

`Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal` will open a terminal window within a container.

`Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal (Local)` will open a terminal on your host machine.

[image]

Latter doesn't seem to have have a key binding assigned, so you may want to add one.

Comment: Yep, this works -- weird that it's not exposed in the terminal menus, either. And it doesn't open to open folder like it normally would. But still helps. Thanks.